# Show these vectors are locally linear dependent modulo $V_{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space given by $V=V_{1}\oplus V_{0}$ with dim $V_{1}=n-1$.

Let $U$ be a vector space given by $U=V\oplus V\oplus\dotsb\oplus V$, the direct sum of n copies of $V$.

Let $T_{i}:U\rightarrow V$ be given by

$$T_{i}(u)=T_{i}(v_{1}\oplus v_{2}\oplus\dotsb\oplus v_{n})=v_{i} \quad i=1,2,\dotsc,n$$

The question is to prove that for each $u \in U$, $T_{1}u, T_{2}u,\dotsc, T_{n}u$ are locally dependent modulo $V_{0}$. That is, we must show for each $u\in U$, $\exists \alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},\dotsc,\alpha_{n}$ not all zero, such that $\alpha_{1}T_{1}u+\alpha_{2}T_{2}u+\dotsb+\alpha_{n}T_{n}u\in V_{0}.$

Comment: Might be handy to have a basis for $V$, chosen so that one member of the basis generated $V_0$.  Then determine whether that one basis element has a preimage under the simultaneous collection of $T_i$s.

Comment: That seems to work. But how do we assume that $V_{0}$ has dimension 1?

Comment: It seems to work in any case, as long as we assume $V_{0}$ is finite dimensional, which is the case. Thanks for the suggestion on using a basis for $V$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mighty complicated formulation for a simple matter (one never uses $u$, so just treat the $v_i=T_i(u)\in V$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ as primitive independent vectors; also "locally" really means nothing).

Let $\pi:V\to V_1$ be the projection on the first summand of $V=V_1\oplus V_0$. Now $\pi(v_1),\ldots,\pi(v_n)\in V_1$ are $n$ vectors, which for dimension reasons must be linearly dependent; let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be coefficients of a nontrivial relation between them. Now $\pi(\alpha_1v_i+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n)=\alpha_1\pi(v_1)+\ldots+\alpha_n\pi(v_n)=0$, so $\alpha_1v_i+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n\in\ker(\pi)=V_0$.